# during runtime the program strucks at frame no 27

Tags: c++, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, opencv3.0, cvblobslib

I have written a program to count no of cars from the captured video. I have installed opencv and cvblob, raspbian wheezy OS on raspberry pi 2. The problem I am facing is "During run time the program hangs at cvLabel after certain no of iterations.

```
IplImage *labelImg =cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(greyImage), IPL_DEPTH_LABEL, 1); 
unsigned int result = cvLabel(greyImage, labelImg,blobs);
```

But when I run the same program on Virtual Machine in my laptop it will run completely. What might be the reason for this..? Please advice

Comment: for me it strucks at frame 42... :D

Comment: Provide a [mcve], or we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my issue. The below changes are required specially for raspberry pi 2(armhf) which avoids the program to run infinite.

https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/issues/detail?id=23

go to `/home/pi/cvblob/cvBlob`

> In cvLabel.h file

`const char movesE ... const char movesI ...`

to

```
const signed char movesE ... const signed char movesI ...
```

> and in cvBlob/cvcontour.cpp , line 84:

change

```
const char cvChainCodeMoves[8][2] = { { 0, -1},
```

to

```
const signed char cvChainCodeMoves[8][2] = { { 0, -1},
```